# Files in internal storage not readable when created manually

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

I was trying to copy files to internal storage using adb on my rooted phone and then accessing them later from the app.

However, while was working on Kitkat, it no longer is for API 23:

```
type=1400 audit(0.0:2965): avc: denied { setattr } for name="files" dev="dm-0" ino=1513285 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:app_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
```

Is there a way to circumvent this or do I need to add the files to the apk as assets?